# MS Outlook 2013 not working in normal mode but works ok in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013

Been working on a laptop for 2 weeks now with this problem and desperately need help.

Regarding this issue, I have search the net for solutions. In case some of you may wonder what solutions I was referring to, click [here](http://office2013issues.blogspot.in/2013/02/fixed-office-2013-has-stopped-working.html#.VRS0z-GV5ev) to see.

I did both fix 1 and 2 but still nothing. All the other MS Office applications are working OK. Have not tried reinstalling as it is single license.

Its a Toshiba Satellite C50-A Windows 7 64-bit laptop.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is there an error code? have you checked the event log?

Comment: Sorry about that. The error message I get is "Microsoft Outlook has stopped working" "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available"

Comment: Have you tried [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that already.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help others with outlook 2013 on windows 7. Otlook is stuck on "loading profile" drove me nuts for 3 days.
I found many advices on google. I tried the steps mentioned steps below:

1. I have cleaned up registry and also disabled all plugins
2. uninstalled office 2013 restarted PC, installed office back on
3. tried office 2016 same issue
4. disabled hardware graphic acceleration via regedit
5. uninstalled my antivirus

None of the above worked for me I googled that *disabling AERO themes in windows 7 will do the job* and it actually did..

Dont waste your time and disable aero in windows, this will fix stuck outlook in a second.

Answer (score 0):

```
To resolve this problem, follow these steps in the order that they are presented.
Part 1: Create a New Profile
Note Because there are several versions of Microsoft Windows, the following steps may be different on your computer. If they are, see your product documentation to complete these steps.

    Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
    If you are not in Classic view, click Switch to Classic View, and then double-click Mail.
    Click Show Profiles.
    Click Prompt for a profile to be used, and then click Add.
    In the Profile Name box, type a descriptive name for the new profile, and then click OK.
    Click Add a new e-mail account, and then click Next.
    Click the appropriate server type for your new e-mail account, and then click Next.
    Follow the instructions that appear on the screen, and then click Finish.

    Note Make sure that you specify a new personal folder file (.pst file). Do not use the existing file.
    Click OK. 

Note Because you do not use the old .pst file while you are troubleshooting, you will not see any of your old .pst folders or files.
Part 2: Rename the Outlook Data Files
Outlook automatically replaces the Extend.dat data file, the Outcmd.dat data file, and the Frmcache.dat data file if these files are missing. To rename the data files and then test to see whether the problem is resolved, follow these steps:

Note Because there are several versions of Microsoft Windows, the following steps may be different on your computer. If they are, see your product documentation to complete these steps.

    Quit all programs.
    Click Start, and then click Search.
    Click All files and folders.
    In the All or part of the file name box, type extend.dat, outcmd.dat, frmcache.dat.
    In the Look in box, click Local Hard Drives.
    Click More advanced options.
    Click to select the Search hidden files and folders check box.
    Click Search to search for the files.

    By default, these files are located in the following folders, where drive is the drive where Windows is installed.
    File Name   Default Location
    Outcmd.dat  drive:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook
    Extend.dat  drive:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook
    Frmcache.dat    drive:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\FORMS
    For each file that appears in the Search Results dialog box, right-click the file, click Rename, type a new name for the file (for example, type extend.old), and then press ENTER.
    Close the Search Results dialog box.
    Start Outlook.
    When you are prompted, click the new profile.
    Create a new task or a new appointment to see whether the problem is resolved. 

Note Outcmd.dat stores any custom changes that you make to your toolbar buttons. If the problem is resolved after you rename this file, you must make the custom toolbar button changes again.
```

**References**

- [Outlook 2007: Troubleshooting Outlook Crashes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2000071)
- ["Could not complete the operation" error message when you create a new task or appointment in Outlook 2002](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320842)
- [How to manage .pst files in Microsoft Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/287070)
- [You receive an error message when you create a new task or appointment or when you exit Outlook 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/823475)

Answer (score 0):

If it runs ok in a safe mode then the problem is with one or more add-ins. You just need to disable all add-ins in Outlook and then enable them one by one to find the troublesome add-in. After that, contact its developers to fix the issue.